# Antlr4 handling of yaml unquoted multi-line strings

Tags: yaml, antlr4

I am trying to build a parser for a limited set of YAML syntax similar to what is shown below using Antlr 4.7:

```
name:
  last: Smith
  first: John
  address:
    street: 123 Main St
            Suite 100
    city: Boston
    state: MA
    zip:  12345
```

I have a grammar (derived from the Python 3 grammar) that works correctly if I put quotes around the "value" strings but fails if I remove them.  It seems that defining the "value" string so matching terminates before the next "tag:" portion of a new block or a "tag: " portion of a new assign statement is the trick.

Does anyone have any ideas or working samples that handle this use case?

Answer (score 1):

It is the indentation of a non-empty line that should end the matching of a plain scalar. If that indentation is not more than the indentation of the current mapping, the scalar ends there.

For example:

```
mapping:
  key: value with
       multiple lines
  key2:
    other value
```

Here, the `value with multiple lines` ends at the line with `key2:`, because it is not indented more than the current mapping (i.e. the value of `mapping:` above). Of course, the last newline character and the indentation of `key2:` is not a part of that scalar's content.

In the YAML specification, this is handled by a production

```
s-indent(n) ::= s-space × n
```

Now in our case, the inner mapping has an indentation of `n=2`, so your scalar would be matched by something like

```
plain-scalar-part (s-indent(3) s-white* plain-scalar-part)*
```

(I don't know Antlr syntax, just assume these are all non-terminals). After the (possibly empty) first line, you match an indentation of more than the parent mapping (so 3 spaces in this case), then there might be even more whitespace (which is not part of the content), and then more content follows. For simplicity, I ignored possible empty lines.

This will not match the line `key2:` because it has too few indentation, which is how the matching of the scalar will end.

Now I do not know how to do something like `s-indent(n)` in Antlr, but the Python grammar should give you the right pointers.